# stylesheet is connected but nothing is happening while doing some changes

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I connected my templete.php to style.css but when I am changing anything in templete.php, it's showing the result but if I change anything in the stylesheet, it shows no result. what should I do?
My website is not live. i am doing it on wamp server.

templete.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <title>SEO SOBER</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda" 
rel="stylesheet"

<head>
<body>
  <header id="particles-js">
    <?php
    include "navbar.php";
    ?>
  </header>
<!--..... header ends.......-->
<div class="clients">
  <h3>Our Clients</h3>
  <img class="client-img" src="images/clients.png">
</div>
<!--clients ends -->
  <div class="container-About">
    <div class="text">
    <h3>SEO SOBER Digital Story</h3>
<p>about company</p>
</div>
<div class="button">
  <a href="#" class="btn"> READ MORE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- about ends -->
  <div class="features">
    <h3>Services</h3>
    <div class="maincontainer">
      <!-- first card-->
      <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront">
          <div class="seo_card">
            <img class="services-image" src="images/seo-gif-10.gif">
            <h4>Search Engine Optimization</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="theback">back of the card</div>
      </div>
      <!-- second card-->
      <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront">
          <div class="seo_card">
            <img class="services-image" src="images/web-design-service.gif">
            <h4>Web Design</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="theback">back of the card</div>
      </div>
      <!-- third card-->
      <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront">
          <div class="seo_card">
            <img  class="services-image" src="images/Development.gif">
            <h4>Web Development</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="theback">back of the card</div>
      </div>
      <!-- fourth card-->
      <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront">
          <div class="seo_card">
            <img class="services-image" src="images/social.gif">
            <h4>Social Media Marketing</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="theback">back of the card</div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- services end-->
<script src="js/particles.js"></script>
<script src="js/particles.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

please tell me what to do...
I am trying to do changes for half an hour but nothing happenes.
I also add the particles effect. is that the problem?

Comment: Does your css file exists beside your php file?

Comment: yes sir, it exists

Comment: i google my problem and found a solution. i add this link in my php file
"<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/yourStyles.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" />"
but after adding this my navigation bar just dissappear.

Comment: If you are using Google Chrome or Firefox, press `CTRL+U` to see source code, then click on css link "style.css" and tell me what you see.

Comment: Use <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=<?php echo(date(" Y-m-d H:i:s ")); ?>"> to force a load of the latest version of your stylesheet.

Comment: i added the above line and my lav bar again dissappear

Comment: another way - if you aren't changing the stylesheet regularly (i.e., you are only testing and need to see the changes for yourself) is to go into Developer Tools (depends on your browser/device how to get there) and then do a 'hard' refresh.  The problem is that browsers cache stylesheets (which is typically good, but stinks for development) and you need to refresh without caching.

Comment: sir who to do a "hard " refresh??

Comment: when i open developer tool>elements
its showing
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
but this line is not written in my file

Comment: or when i click <li> part in elements it shows

"li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}"
in styles whit a statement
" user agent stylesheet "
but this line is also not mention in my stylesheet

Comment: Try openening css file itself (put something like http://www.something.com/style/style.css in URL)  in browser and then try to reload it by ctrl+r.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are loading your cache, you have to hard reset your page. Try reloading like this on your page:

```
> -Hold the Ctrl key and press the F5 key.

> -Hold the ⇧ Shift key and click the Reload button on the navigation toolbar.

> -Hold the Ctrl key and click the Reload button on the navigation toolbar.

> -Hold the ⇧ Shift key and press the F5 key.
```